# Mapping drives to SharePoint folders - connectivity always breaking

Tags: folder, connection, mapped-folder, network-drive

Good morning.  I work in a group that frequently uses SharePoint 365 libraries and favor accessing materials through Windows Explorer (rather than navigating through the Internet Explorer webpage links).  We are able to map network drives to specific SharePoint 365 folders but are constantly forced to "re-establish" connection with the SharePoint site because the mapped connection breaks.  The workaround is to go into SharePoint, access the library, click "Open in Explorer", click several layers into the folders and then the mapped drive will work again.  It's a major pain point... any thoughts on what we can do to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some third party tools that can help with this, but the reality is that this is working "as designed". User cookies expire periodically and lock the users out until they are refreshed.

There is some PowerShell that can be run to help, but to be honest, I haven't seen it make much difference.

```
Get-SPOTenant | Select UsePersistentCookiesForExplorerView
Set-SPOTenant -UsePersistentCookiesForExplorerView $True
```

I believe the general guidance is to use the next gen OneDrive for Business sync client to sync the content down to the local machine. Using the NGSC, you can selective sync folders you want so you don't have to pull down the entire structure.

Comment: Just to clarify - Using NGSC, will users be able to create shortcuts or "map drives" to folder locations and in essence, be able to navigate through files and folders using windows explorer without the constant breaking?

Comment: The libraries will be synced down to their local machine and are available in Windows Explorer, any adds/edits/deletes they make to the synced library will be replicated up and any changes others make will be synced down to them.

Comment: So our ideal state will be available upon moving to NGSC

Comment: It should, so long as you have the hard drive space to accommodate syncing the content down

Comment: @EricAlexander I am not finding any behaviour difference after using the command Set-SPOTenant -UsePersistentCookiesForExplorerView $True . not sure whether persistant cookie works here. if you can let me know the name of the cookies i can try to find out whether its available

Comment: Can you provide a(n official) source for "the general guidance is to use the next gen OneDrive for Business sync client to sync the content down to the local machine"? I need to show that to my management.

Comment: Found the page with the recommendation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/administration/troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives